# What is the range of the long double C++

Tags: c++, types, numbers, primitive-types

What is the range of long double in C++?

Answer (score 14):

[`#include <limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

```
std::numeric_limits<long double>::min()
//...
std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()
```

The definition of [`long double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) is compiler & platform dependent, it is at least the same as a `double`, thus, it may take 8, 12 (usually also for 80bits) or even 16 bytes ([float128/quadruple precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)) and has a range according to its size.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to find out.

Answer (score 4):

It is system (and processor, and compiler, and ABI) dependent. Look into `<limits.h>` and `<math.h>` and `<float.h>` standard headers.

Comment: it's even compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN - [Data Type Ranges (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and the [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/), the *long double* is the same as *double*, takes 8 bytes of space and lies in the range [-1.7E+308, 1.7E+308].

There are also other sites, like [this](http://www.technoexam.com/c-language-lecture-study-notes-tutorials-material/data-types-enum-typedef.asp), which says that *long double* takes 12 - 16 bytes.