# what is the exact range of long double in c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, long-double

I've been googling for hours and still can't find the exact results of **"what is the range of long double in c++"**. some say `long double` is the same as `double`. but sizeof double is 8 bytes and sizeof long double is 16 bytes. note that I'm using gcc.

Comment: 1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types 2) One can just simply print out `std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()`, and `std::numeric_limits<long double>::min()` to figure out the range on your system.

Comment: it depends: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision

Comment: You can't find a definitive answer because most such ranges are implementation-dependent.

Comment: in my case, i'm asking 128-bit floating point integers @molbdnilo .

Comment: Please note that some of those 16 bytes may be just padding.

Comment: note that even if `sizeof(long double)` is 16 bytes, it doesn't mean that all the bits are significant. Some may just be padding. Duplicates: [What is the size of float and double in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25524355/995714), [What is the range of the long double C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15320756/995714), [long double vs double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3454576/995714), [Difference between long double and double in C and C++ (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14221612/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of float and double in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524355/what-is-the-size-of-float-and-double-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not ask your compiler? `std::numeric_limits<long double>` is defined.

```
long double smallest = std::numeric_limits<long double>::min();
long double largest = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max();
long double lowest = std::numeric_limits<long double>::lowest();
std::cout << "lowest " << lowest << std::endl;
std::cout << "largest " << largest << std::endl;
std::cout << "smallest " << smallest << std::endl;
```

Running this code on [godbolt.org with x86-64 GCC 11.2](https://godbolt.org/z/sfoo5aPeb) gives me:

```
lowest -1.18973e+4932
largest 1.18973e+4932
smallest 3.3621e-4932
```

It might vary for your platform, of course.

Comment: Please add log base 2 values.

Comment: You'd need `lowest` to see the largest negative number in magnitude and thus the full "range".

Comment: Please note that those results are compatible with a [double extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) 80-bit format.